# how to take substring in ksh

Tags: unix, awk, substring, ksh, cut

I have a file named "output.txt" having data in format:

```
400949703|2000025967912|20130614010652|20130614131543
355949737|2144050263|20120407100407|20120407101307
355499738|2144500262|20110911010901|20110911135601
```

I am executing an awk command as shown below:

```
awk -F"|" '{num1="`echo $3| cut -c1-8`"; print $num1}' output.txt
```

My expected output is :

```
20130614
20120407
20110911
```

But I am getting output as what is actually the input.

```
400949703|2000025967912|20130614010652|20130614131543
355949737|2144050263|20120407100407|20120407101307
355499738|2144500262|20110911010901|20110911135601
```

Not able to find out the reason. My task is to compare the 1st 8 characters in 3rd and 4th column. But stucked at this part only.

Experts, kindly help me to get the way, where I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `cut` twice?

```
$ cut -d'|' -f4 file | cut -c-8
20130614
20120407
20110911
```

- Firstly to get the 4th field based on `|` delimiter.
- Secondly to get the first 8 characters (note that `cut -c-8` is the same as your `cut -c1-8`)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing bash with awk, one tool is just enough:

```
awk -F\| 'a=substr($3, 1, 8){if(a==substr($4, 1, 8)){print a}}' output.txt
```

Get substrings of columns 3 and 4 , compare it and print if its ok.